# Unable to push custom reports(html or xml format) from jenkins to hygieia dashboard

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hygieia

I have custom generated XML test reports that is pushed to jenkins.  I tried '`HygieiaTestPublishStep`' using hygieia-jenkis plugin, but it does not pick the data(Logs pasted below). Hygieia jenkins collector also do not pick these files.

> [Pipeline] hygieiaTestPublishStep Hygieia: Published Build Data For
>   Test Publishing. Response Code: 201. Response Value= 5b2cd5ee9b89f4176
>
> Hygieia Test Result Publisher - Looking for file pattern '*.xml' in
>   directory  Hygieia Test Publisher: Processing file:
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testdisplay/SAMPLE-UNITTEST/unitTest/UnitTestReport.xml
>   Hygieia Publisher: Error Parsing File:
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testdisplay/SAMPLE-UNITTEST/unitTest/UnitTestReport.xml
>   Hygieia: Published Test Data. Nothing to publish

---

How do i to push it to hygieia dashboard from jenkins? What is the sample XML format that the plugin '`HygieiaTestPublishStep`' accept?

Comment: Have you got it working? can publish the solution or how you got around it.

Answer (score 0):

For other test reports like junit xml reports, created a new custom collector and a corresponding widget(for reference please have look at code analysis widget code. it has a unit test related REST API).

In this case, we push test reports to a particular path from where the custom collector would  parse and update in the 'test_results' mongodb collection based with jobName, executionId and test type as entry identifiers.

Custom collector documentation link:
[Hygieia custom collector](https://hygieia.github.io/Hygieia/create_collector.html)